# using shell32 inside C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, shell32

I am trying to use some code that uses the `IID_IShellDispatch` and `CLSID_Shell` constants.

My includes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinDef.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ShlDisp.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
```

The code:

```
    BSTR source = SysAllocString(input.toStdWString().c_str());
    BSTR dest = SysAllocString(outputDirectory.toStdWString().c_str());
    HRESULT result;
    IShellDispatch *pISD;
    Folder *folder = NULL;
    VARIANT vDir, vFile, vOpt;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&pISD);
    ...
```

The last line above throws error about undefined reference to CLSID_Shell and IID_IShellDispatch

The code is part of a Qt project so I am using a Qt project file (for qmake) and I have added the `-lshell32` into the `LIBS` section of it:

```
LIBS += -lshell32 -loleaut32 -lole32
```

Command executed is

```
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\wallch.exe object_script.wallch.Debug  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -lshell32 -loleaut32 -lole32 -LC:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Networkd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored
```

Using MinGW on win7

Comment: `in my compiler options` is insufficient detail. For example, order matters. What is your testcase? Be _specific_ and _precise_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You are right. Question updated.

Comment: Nope, still not good enough. We cannot see your build command. We didn't need to know that you're using Qt — abstract that out of your question. **Make a [testcase](http://sscce.org)**

Comment: Clsid and Iid values are usually in uuid.lb.

Comment: Question has been updated again. I don't think that creating a testcase would be necessary :) I think I've given all the important info.

Comment: @RaymondChen No, it's not there. I can see it inside `ShlDisp.h` though

Comment: Worst case you can always use `INITGUID` to create your own copy.

Comment: Well, it would be better to understand and solve the problem rather than bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the windows SDK and add it to my options like this:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib" -loleaut32 -lshell32 -luuid -lole32
```